# Data frame return values as NaN despite no NaNs?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nan

I have a dataframe read from a csv file. When feeding a random forest or SVM model with this data I get the error respone

```
"ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')."
```

So when I check my dataframe for NaN values it returns my whole data frame as NaN values. However, when I print an arbitrary cell in my dataframe it gives me the correct data point and not a NaN. Anyone that knows what's going on here?

Using the code below to retrieve my NaN values:

```
X_test.isnull().values.any()
```

(returns True)

```
null_rows = X_test[X_test.isnull()]
print(null_rows)

 lag k = -1  lag k = -2  lag k = -3  lag k = 1  lag k = 2  lag k = 3  \
137354         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137355         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137356         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137357         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137358         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137359         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137360         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137361         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137362         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137363         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137364         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137365         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137366         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137367         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137368         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137369         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137370         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137371         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137372         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137373         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137374         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137375         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137376         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137377         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137378         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137379         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137380         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137381         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137382         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
137383         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
...            ...         ...         ...        ...        ...        ...   
140176         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140177         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140178         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140179         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140180         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140181         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140182         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140183         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140184         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140185         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140186         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140187         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140188         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140189         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140190         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140191         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140192         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140193         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140194         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140195         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140196         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140197         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140198         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140199         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140200         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140201         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140202         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140203         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140204         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
140205         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   

        lag k = 23  lag k = 24  lag k = 48  Hour_0   ...     Hour_14  Hour_15  \
137354         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137355         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137356         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137357         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137358         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137359         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137360         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137361         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137362         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137363         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137364         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137365         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137366         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137367         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137368         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137369         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137370         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137371         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137372         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137373         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137374         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137375         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137376         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137377         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137378         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137379         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137380         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137381         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137382         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
137383         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
...            ...         ...         ...     ...   ...         ...      ...   
140176         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140177         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140178         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140179         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140180         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140181         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140182         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140183         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140184         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140185         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140186         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140187         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140188         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140189         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140190         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140191         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140192         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140193         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140194         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140195         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140196         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140197         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140198         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140199         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140200         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140201         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140202         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140203         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140204         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   
140205         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN   

        Hour_16  Hour_17  Hour_18  Hour_19  Hour_20  Hour_21  Hour_22  Hour_23  
137354      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137355      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137356      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137357      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137358      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137359      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137360      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137361      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137362      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137363      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137364      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137365      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137366      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137367      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137368      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137369      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137370      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137371      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137372      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137373      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137374      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137375      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137376      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137377      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137378      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137379      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137380      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137381      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137382      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
137383      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
...         ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...  
140176      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140177      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140178      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140179      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140180      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140181      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140182      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140183      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140184      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140185      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140186      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140187      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140188      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140189      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140190      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140191      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140192      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140193      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140194      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140195      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140196      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140197      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140198      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140199      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140200      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140201      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140202      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140203      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140204      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
140205      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  

[2852 rows x 33 columns]
```

Checking the first row gives:

```
display((X_test.loc[[137354]].isnull().any()))


lag k = -1    False
lag k = -2    False
lag k = -3    False
lag k = 1     False
lag k = 2     False
lag k = 3     False
lag k = 23    False
lag k = 24    False
lag k = 48    False
Hour_0        False
Hour_1        False
Hour_2        False
Hour_3        False
Hour_4        False
Hour_5        False
Hour_6        False
Hour_7        False
Hour_8        False
Hour_9        False
Hour_10       False
Hour_11       False
Hour_12       False
Hour_13       False
Hour_14       False
Hour_15       False
Hour_16       False
Hour_17       False
Hour_18       False
Hour_19       False
Hour_20       False
Hour_21       False
Hour_22       False
Hour_23       False
dtype: bool
```

Hence, I don't understand why my models say I am feeding NaN or why the above lines of code indicates there are NaNs in the dataset.

Appreciate any feedback

Thanks!

Comment: `X_test[X_test.isnull()]` doesn't do what you think it does. It will return `NaN`s anyway, not only on `NaN` cells (it returns `NaN`s in `false` cells, and shows the true value in `true` cells. Since true values are `NaN`s, you'll get all `NaN`s). To better investigate this, do `X_test.isnull().idxmax()` and then you'll have `ids` where you'll find `NaN`s. Of course, that'll return only the first occurrence of `NaN`, but its a start for you to investigate where you can find the nulls.

Comment: Thanks for you response Rafael. I assumed I made some misconception with the data extraction. However, after following your advice, X_test.isnull().idxmax() also returns supposedly indexes with NaN value that turn out to not be NaNs. Do you if this issue could occur by any other reason? I have also checked the source data, for those indexes which don't show any appearant misalignments compared to the rest of the data which is loaded correctly. Thanks